# SQL, select value from row with distinct attribute but max value of another attribute

Tags: sql, max, distinct

I have, for example, this table:

| id | name | campagna | valore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | u1 | 1 | 22 |
| 2 | u1 | 2 | 23 |
| 4 | u2 | 1 | 223 |
| 5 | u3 | 2 | 223 |

I would select rows that have name value unique(distinct) but the row that has max(campagna) between the rows with same name .
For example I would have :

| name | campagna | valore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| u1 | 2 | 23 |
| u2 | 1 | 223 |
| u3 | 2 | 223 |

Can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You want one result row per name. The row to pick per name is the one with the maximum capagna for the name.

This is usually done with an analytic function, e.g.:

```
select name, campagna, valore
from
(
  select t.*, max(campagna) over (partition by name) as max_campagna
  from mytable t
)
where campagna = max_campagna
order by name;
```

But it can be achieved with other methods, too. E.g.:

```
select *
from mytable
where (name, campagna) in
(
  select name, max(campagna)
  from mytable
  group by name
)
order by name;
```

or

```
select *
from mytable t
where not exists
(
  select null
  from mytable t2
  where t2.name = t.name
  and t2.campagna > t.campagna
)
order by name;
```